# How to do aggregation at the sametime for few columns in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I process a single file which contains columns, date, id, product, sale,delivery.
I want to sum up based more than one raws, if they occurred on same day for same id and product.

```
  data = data.groupby(['Date', 'Id', 'Product']).agg({'sale': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

How can i add, sum up the deliveries too in above line?

```
eg:
```

Input

```
Date   Id   Product Sale  deliveries
01/09  1000  A       1000  500
01/09  1000 A         350  0

02/09  1001   B      1100  555
02/09  1001  B       333   222
```

output

```
Date   Id    Product   Sale    deliveries
01/09  1000   A        1350    500
02/09  10001   B       1433    777
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify column in list for aggregation:

```
data = data.groupby(['Date', 'Id', 'Product'])['Sale','deliveries'].sum().reset_index()
```

If need procesing all another columns is necessary aggregation for each of them, e.g. `mean`, `first`, `last`:

```
data = (data.groupby(['Date', 'Id', 'Product'])
            .agg({'sale': 'sum', 'deliveries':'sum', 'another col': 'mean'})
            .reset_index())
```

Comment: After the group by I miss the first column. That means if my file contain, company,date, id, prodcut,sale,delivery columns.. after above groupby, i miss the first column that is company

Comment: @Ratha - Column `Date` ?

Comment: No Company ..print(data.dtypes)
    print('yyy')
    data = data.groupby(['Date', 'SiteCode', 'Product Name'])['Sale Volume','Deliveries Volume',
                                                                   'Dip Volume'].sum().reset_index()
    print(data.dtypes)

Comment: Last datatype print misses my one column

Comment: @Ratha - It is strings in `Company` ? If yes, then need first company per groups? Or join all company strings names by `,` ?

Comment: That column contain same value for all rows. Means per file  contain records from same company .And yes it is string

Comment: @Ratha - So use `data = (data.groupby(['Date', 'Id', 'Product'])
            .agg({'Sale Volume': 'sum', 'Deliveries Volume':'sum', 'Dip Volume': 'sum', 'Company':'first'})
            .reset_index())`

Comment: Thanks that works.Why earlier solution skipped one column?

Comment: @Ratha - Because is not specified - it sum only columns from list `['Sale Volume','Deliveries Volume', 'Dip Volume']`, and there is no `Company`, because not need it. Btw, another solution is `data = data.groupby(['Company','Date', 'SiteCode', 'Product Name'])['Sale Volume','Deliveries Volume', 'Dip Volume'].sum().reset_index()` - add `company` to `groupby`

Answer (score 1):

Just do a `sum`:

```
df.groupby(["Date","Id","Product"])["Sale","deliveries"].sum().reset_index()

#
    Date    Id Product  Sale  deliveries
0  01/09  1000       A  1350         500
1  02/09  1001       B  1433         777
```

Comment: I have another columns too, which I dont wnat to sum up, eg: RecordId, tankId. I wnat to specifically mention which columns to sumup

Comment: I was editing it and didn't see. Good answer as always @jezrael with added scenarios :)